# Sequence animations using Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I am trying to create two sequential animations using Flutter. Both are using Curves.easeIn, and the second one starts on top of the first one, instead of from 0. Image a car starts to move from 0 to 50 miles/hours, after it runs a few while, it speeds to 70 miles/hour **from 50 miles/hour instead of 0 miles/hour**.  How can I do it?
I am aware of and using TweenSequence, but I can't figure out a way to make it work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to see what exactly it is that you've tried to ensure that we're not just flying blind here and missing your point, but I can point you to the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html) and provide:

```dart
final Animation<double> animation = TweenSequence<double>(
  <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 50.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
      weight: 40.0,
    ),
    // This may be optional for you: this should keep the animation at a given point.
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(50.0),
      weight: 20.0,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 50.0, end: 70.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn)),
      weight: 40.0,
    ),
  ],
).animate(myAnimationController);
```

Happy to take a deeper look if you can add the code that's giving you trouble, and I can modify my answer to be more bespoke if needed. Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks, @joseph. I am aware of the example. My scenario is like the car example in my question. It's hard to explain in another way.

Comment: I might understand, and I'm sorry for echoing the docs. Let me try again and see if maybe I can suggest a different approach. I needed to do something which (maybe) is similar to what you're trying to accomplish so maybe it would help you. I just need to generalize it and explain it. Hopefully we can still figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageAnimationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageAnimationExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageAnimationExample> createState() => _PageAnimationExampleState();
}

class _PageAnimationExampleState extends State<PageAnimationExample>
    // If you need two or more animation controllers be sure to use
    //  [TickerProviderStateMixin] instead of [SingleTickerProviderStateMixin]
    with
        SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> animation1;
  late Animation<double> animation2;

  // This can be whatever duration you want
  static const Duration _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 3000);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Create an [AnimationController] to drive the animations: both animations
    //  can share a controller as long as they are both supposed to share the
    //  same animation duration
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration)
      // Note: you'll need to setState to force a rebuild. You can avoid this
      //  step if you use an [AnimatedBuilder] widget instead and provide the
      //  animationController as the controller.
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    // We'll need two animations, the first of which will animate from 0.0-1.0
    //  but only on the first half of the curve (0.0 - 0.5). The second will run
    //  only on the second half of the curve (0.5 - 1.0).

    // The tricky thing is that Flutter doesn't directly support cutting curves.
    //  You can string together two curves with similar momentum/movement though
    //  such that the result feels like a single animation. I'll give more
    //  examples below.

    // For easeIn, see if a combo of [easeIn] at first and then [linear] would
    //  work for you. Keep in mind that if you wanted to keep the linear
    //  component with the same slope as where your first curve ends, you could
    //  adjust the interval to have the first curve take longer/shorter and the
    //  second curve to be shorter/longer. Imagine them like stacking.

    animation1 = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: const Interval(
          // The first half of the animation only, using the given curve
          0.0,
          // TODO: you can overlap these intervals too, to have one curve start
          //  before the first one is done. Try this one as 0.67 and the below
          //  as 0.33 as an example

          0.5,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        ),
      ),
    );

    // NOTE: You can contrary to what I mentioned above, you can leave a gap
    //  between when your curves start and end if you need to have a pause

    animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: const Interval(
          // The second half of the animation only, using the given curve
          0.5,
          1.0,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        ),
      ),
    );

    _animate();
  }

  /// This function runs the animation from 0.0 - 1.0
  void _animate() {
    animationController.reset();
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            // Example
            // The ball should move to the right, then up, sharing the same curve
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(
                    animation1.value,
                    -animation2.value,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 10.0,
                    width: 10.0,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // Reset button - you can re-run with these
            Center(
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: _animate,
                child: Text('reset'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}

// If you're really hell-bent you can create your own curve by extending the
//  Curve class and giving fine-grained control over how fast the curve reaches
//  its terminus so that the curves would work as you want them to.

/// A silly curve that races to the end point in the first third of the
/// animation, returns to the start in the middle third of the animation, and
/// then returns to the end point in the last third of the animation
class LinearCurve extends Curve {
  // You can provide whatever arguments you want, like any other class.

  const LinearCurve();

  // Override the transform function to convert an input number from 0 - 1 to
  //  another number from 0 - 1
  @override
  double transform(double t) => t.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Note it's sort of a pain because Flutter doesn't natively support what I think you're trying to achieve of sharing a curve's momentum across animation intervals.

Without knowing your exact use case I can't provide a great example that demonstrates the curve nicely; using the curve as I am here to move the same widget just in a different direction is a little silly, but I'm hoping maybe this is close enough to be useful to you?

Comment: Thank you, Joeseph. I appreciate your help. What I have is similar to your example. Mine is the first one Curve.easeIn and the second Curve.linear. It's kind of what I want except there is a jump between the two animations. Ideally it's a smooth increase/decrease instead of a jump. I also tried to customized the curve, but could not figure out a generic solution...